# I am trying to fix the Nuxt Js Mixed content error, unable to solve

Tags: vue.js, axios, proxy, nuxt.js

I am getting bellow error

### Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://x.xxx.1x.xxx:x000/api/v1/users/slots?type=NIGHT&duration='.

But in localhost site runs smoothly with no issues. Only when i upload the build to online then i am getting this error.

this is how i configured Axios

```
  axios: {
    proxy: true 
  },
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://x.xxx.x1.xxx:x000/api/v1',
  },
```

Comment: Try to add an `s` to the `http` part of `http://x.xxx.1x.xxx:x000/api/v1/users/slots?type=NIGHT&duration=`

Comment: Also, there is a `security` tab in your devtools where those kind of warnings are all listed. Overall, all the websites kowadays should be HTTPS anyway since you get worse reputation otherwise.

Comment: @kissu is there no other way to fix it? instead of using https??

Comment: The error is stating that you do have `http` and `https` mixed together. So, by-passing that is feasible locally but will still impact your production app by displaying a scary warning to your visitors + drop the reputation of your website. Why is SSL such an issue? Can't you use Letsencrypt to setup a free certificate? Some platforms/hosts can even do that for you.

Comment: @kissu You are right but i am having issue with hosting api in hostinger VPS ngnix is not running and throwing errors. so i am running api via ip address. do you think we can install SSL in VPS ip? from http to https?? i built API using node/express

Comment: You need to figure out how to install your certificate on Hostinger, you can always use another platform to host your node app like Heroku or Railway. HTTPS is very easy with those.

Comment: I will go with AWS then?

Comment: AWS is not the simplest since you will need to do things yourself. I've recommended some easy-to-use platforms in my previous comment.